# Ember RESTAdapter not populating my store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

i'm trying to write a simple ember application based on RESTful API. My code looks like that:

#### store.js.coffee

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen
  namespace: 'api/v1'

EmberClient.Store = DS.Store.extend
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
```

#### routes/songs.js.coffee

```
EmberClient.SongsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @get('store').findAll('Song')
```

#### models/song.js.coffee

```
EmberClient.Song = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
```

#### api response:

```
{"songs":[{"id":10,"title":"Intro"},{"id":12,"title":"Fantasy"}]}
```

The thing is, i'm not able to loop through the results in my template cause the store is null. Request to my API is fired, api response is returned but EmberInspector says, that `EmberClient.Song` has 0 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors

1- Change your store definition to `adapter: DS.RESTAdapter` instead of `adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()`:

```
EmberClient.Store = DS.Store.extend
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter
```

If you remove the code above will work too, because ember by default use the `DS.RESTAdapter`.

2 - Use `findAll('song')` instead of `findAll('Song')`

Here is a jsbin with this working http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ItujOnO/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for this :) Unfortunately it's not working for me. 1) If i remove it (this whole block of code), it throws `Assertion failed: You included Ember Data but didn't define EmberClient.Store`. 2) i can't use a lowercased model name cause then, the api url is wrong (it cut's off the first char), see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15734236/552936

Comment: No problem. My code target the ember-data 1.3.0-beta.x version, what is your current?

Comment: Mine ember is 1.2.0, jquery 1.10.2

Comment: And what is the ember data version?

Comment: ok it was caused by wrong versions of libs (i'm using it with Ruby on Rails). I have updated ember-data to 1.0.0-beta.2 and it's working now. Thank you for your help :)